# How to ensure Hikari connections are spawn with latest credentials?

Tags: spring, database-connection, amazon-iam, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am using IAM credentials for my Spring DataSource to connect to Database. IAM credentials expire in 15 minutes. So the `spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifeTime` is set to 14 minutes.

However, the service runs properly for only 15 minutes. After that I see `"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: PAM authentication failed for user ...` error.

I suspect this issue is due to the Hikari connections running with outdated credentials.

However, I don't understand why the new Hikari connections, which are created after existing connection timeouts, are not loading the new IAM credentials.

Here is my Datasource:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Value("${database.url:null}")
    private String dataBaseURL;

    @Value("${database.username:null}")
    private String username;

    @Bean
    @Profile("postgres")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url(dataBaseURL);
        dataSourceBuilder.username(username);

//        extracting IAM credentials by calling IAM Token generator.
        dataSourceBuilder.password(RdsIamHikariDataSource.getPassword(dataBaseURL, username));
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should they? The password is set at startup time and not refetched each time a connection is being made.

Comment: @M.Deinum This is not the static password. This is an IAM credential that expires every 15 minutes. Hence the need.

Comment: Your current setup won't work (as stated before). The password is retrieved at startup and the bean is build. The password is simply never refreshed. If your passwords rotate why even bother with a connection pool as it is broken a lot of times. Instead I would suggest creating a subclass of `DriverManagerDataSource` and override the `getPassword` to always retrieve a new one (or check for a timeout on the password or whatever is implemented).

Comment: Looking at the `RdsIamHikariDataSource` you are doing something like (https://blog.jdriven.com/2021/06/configure-hikari-connection-pool-when-using-rds-iam/) and doing it wrong. Don't use the `DataSourceBuilder` to return a datasource but return an instance of the `RdsIamHikariDataSource` which has an overridden `getPassword` method (which you made static for whatever reason).

Answer (score 0):

Doing a google on the classname leads to [this blog post](https://blog.jdriven.com/2021/06/configure-hikari-connection-pool-when-using-rds-iam/). Assuming you are attempting to follow that (and haven't got it to work). Do the following.

Add the following to your `application.properties`.

```
spring.datasource.url=<your-url>
spring.datasource.username=<your-iam-role>
spring.datasource.type=package.of.your.RdsIamHikariDataSource
```

In your java config remove your `DatabaseConfiguration`, Spring Boot auto configuration will now take care of creating the proper datasource.